# I want to keep a long process running in the background in django

Tags: python, django, celery, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I am a beginner in django.

I want to keep running long processes in django in the background.

And I want to keep it running unless I explicitly end that process.

I can't figure out where and how to add the following code to django.

```
import threading
import asyncio


class long_task:
    def __init__(self):
        self.continue_flag = True

    async def long_task(self,):
        print('long task start...')
        i = 0
        while self.continue_flag:
            print(i)
            await asyncio.sleep(3)
            i = i+1

    def stop(self):
        self.continue_flag = False


def run_loop(loop):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    print('main loop start...')
    loop.run_forever()


def ask_loop_stop(loop):
    print("main loop stop")
    loop.call_soon_threadsafe(loop.stop)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
threading.Thread(target=run_loop, args=(loop,)).start()
print('main loop is ready')

long_task_1 = long_task()
asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(long_task_1.long_task(), loop)
```

I will elaborate on what I want to do.

1. Run a loop when django starts.
2. Add long_task to the loop at any given time (when a specific event
   occurs by monitoring an external site).
3. Keep the program running in the background so that the site can be
   viewed. In the future I would like to display the results of this
   program on a page.
4. Close the loop at another time (during maintenance).

Here's what I've tried

1. Register and execute as a task using celery and celery-beat.

=>

Can't specify that a program should be run when django starts

2. Create a custom task in django and run it with a command.

.

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Start Main Loop"

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('-i', default=1, type=int, help='UserId')

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        id = options['i']
        print("UserId:{},".format(id))

        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        threading.Thread(target=run_loop, args=(loop,)).start()
        print('main loop is ready')
```

=>
I get an following error and can't run it.

”django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.”

I also don't know what I can do when I start django.

3. Add the code to init.py.

.

```
import asyncio
import threading
import time
from app import long_task

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
threading.Thread(target=long_task.run_loop, args=(loop,)).start()
print('main loop is ready')
```

=>

I get an following error and can't run it.

”You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.”

--Environment--

- Windows10 64bit
- Python (3.7)
- Redis server (3.0.504)
- Django (3.2.3)
- celery (5.0.5)
- django-celery-beat (2.2.0)
- django-celery-results (2.0.1)
- PostgreSQL (13)

Please tell me how to make this happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AsyncIO event loops are not thread safe; you can't run the loop from a different thread than it was originally created on. Your `run_loop` function should instead take no arguments, and create/start a new event loop to run your coroutine:

```py
LOOP = None

def run_loop():
    global LOOP
    LOOP = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    LOOP.run_until_complete(long_running_task())

threading.Thread(target=run_loop).start()

# <do other things>

LOOP.call_soon_threadsafe(LOOP.stop)
```

Comment: You are a genius.
I was able to do what I wanted to do.
And your explanation helped me to understand the cause of my problem.
It is amazing that you can read my poor explanation and give an accurate answer in such a short time.
I have consumed a lot of time on this problem.
You were able to solve this problem in an instant.
I admire you.
Thank you very much.